# Integrability of a function on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

Let us consider the function on $\mathbb{R}$ as

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} \frac {1}{\sqrt{x}} & \text{if } 0<x<1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$

Then show that the function is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is this asking about Riemann Integrability of $f$?

$0$ is a point of infinite discontinuity of $f$, but $f$ is bounded and integrable on $[0+\delta,1]$ for all $\delta$ satisfying $0< \delta <1$. $f$ is unbounded in a nbd of $0$, so it can't be Riemann integrable. By the way the integral is improper and convergent and

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=2.$$.

My question is, what is the correct conclusion of the question? Please help me.

Comment: No one here knows the context for this problem more than you, so we can't really help you interpret it better than you can yourself. I agree with all of your thoughts on the problem, but I don't know the answer to any of your questions. It depends on context, which only you have. For that reason, I'm voting to close due to a lack of context.